# Apple Distribution vs "3rd Party" certificates

Tags: macos, codesign, mac-app-store

I have a Mac app distributed in the Mac App Store.

Previously, I would sign the compiled app with my "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" certificate, and then in the `productbuild` command it would create a `.pkg` and sign it with my "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" certificate.

1. Are both of these now [replaced](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes#Signing-and-Distribution) with the "Apple Distribution"
   certificate?
2. Do I still need a "Mac Installer Distribution" certificate to sign
   the .pkg?

Comment: I just added a bounty. I have the same question

Answer (score 7):

Short answer:

1. Yes.
2. No.

A bit of a background: in Xcode 11, two new certificate types ("Apple Development" and "Apple Distribution") [were added](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes#Signing-and-Distribution) to encourage the application development of [platform-agnostic applications](https://developer.apple.com/macos/iphone-and-ipad-apps/) for the Apple's [own ARM platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1).

Previously,  developers of platform-agnostic applications might've been confused when they had to **choose** between the "iOS Distribution" and "Mac Distribution" certificate types, since an ARM application runs just fine **both** on iOS-based devices and M1-based Macs. The new certificate types remove that ambiguity.

Additionally, within this conceptual model, the "Mac *App* Distribution" (colloquially known as the "3rd Party Mac Developer *Application*", used for `codesign`) and "Mac *Installer* Distribution" (or "3rd Party Mac Developer *Installer*", used for `productbuild`) are now one certificate type "Apple Distribution", i.e. the "Apple Distribution" certificate is now able to do code signing.

You may still use the existing "Mac App Distribution" certificate for code signing and the "Mac Installer Distribution" certificate for product builds, but new certificates you create in Xcode 11 would use the new types.

Comment: Thanks, perfect explanation!

Comment: I'm not sure if it is exactly true, that the `Apple Distribution` certificate is usable with `productbuild` as when done, it throws:
```
productbuild: error: Cannot write product to "./some.pkg". (Could not find appropriate signing identity for “Apple Distribution: XXX”. An installer signing identity (not an application signing identity) is required for signing flat-style products.)
```

Comment: @Oldes which macOS and Xcode versions are you at?

Comment: @Oldes as of Catalina, neither `productbuild` nor `productsign` are able to produce such an error message: https://gist.github.com/ximaera/a01cc3f7bf7fac61707d73d5127a9c2e

Comment: @ximaera I'm on Xcode 13.2, Big Sur, M1

Comment: Check this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665901

_an Apple Development signing identity is a code signing identity and thus not appropriate for signing an installer package_

The reality is, that I have the same error even with the `Apple Distribution` certificate

Comment: Thanks. That was a nightmare to figure it out. googling is hard for this.